# Partial Views in ASP.NET MVC 3 Member Login & Administrator login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am basically try to create two partial views, one for the admin and one for the member.

```
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial1")  |
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
```

thats the code for _LogOnPartial1.

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>Welcome <strong>User</strong>!||
@Html.ActionLink("Account", "Index", "") ||
 @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") </text>}else {
@: @Html.ActionLink("Members", "Index", "Members") }
```

thats the code for _LogOnPartial.

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>Welcome <strong>Administrator</strong>!||
@Html.ActionLink("Account", "Index", "AdminDVD") ||
 @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") </text>}else {
@: @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin") }
```

but when the admin logs in he can see both partial views. i get this.

**Welcome User! || Account || Log Off | Welcome Administrator! || Account || Log Off |**

any way i can separate the admin partial view to the member partial view

Comment: You've checked that a user is authenticated, but shouldn't you check for role membership?

Comment: You haven't mentioned for what case you want an `Admin` login and what case you need a `member` login? Do you want to show different logins on different areas?

Comment: basically the admin has his own database table and the member has their own database table therefore have a different login page.

Answer (score 3):

You could test the roles of the user:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial1")
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
}
```

or do this test directly into the partial and thus you could have only one partial.